# How to link the execution of QProcess and the advancement of the QProgressBar for a very heavy computation loop

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprocess, qprogressbar

I have the following bash script to be executed on a GUI via `QPushButton`:

```
 #!/bin/bash

rostopic echo -b test_LaserScan_PointCloud2_test2.bag -p /scan > test_landing_test_2.csv
rostopic echo -b test_LaserScan_PointCloud2_test2.bag -p /velodyne_points > vel_test_2.csv
```

The script will go through each file and extract the related `.csv`. The process is heavy and it takes a little bit. **The problem** is that there is no way to know how long it takes unless I put a `QProgressBar`, but I don't know how properly link the execution of the `QProcess` and the advancement of the `QProgressBar` correctly.

[image: pbar]

As of now the extraction happens successfully but the `QProgressBar` is not moving from 0.

Below I created a minimal verifiable example and for completeness the source code can be found here:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QProcess>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(float progress READ progress NOTIFY progressChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool running READ running NOTIFY runningChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool finished READ finished NOTIFY finishedChanged)

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    float progress();
    bool running();
    bool finished();

public Q_SLOTS:
    void startComputation();
    void finishComputation();
    void updateProgress(int value);

signals:
    void progressChanged();
    void runningChanged();
    void finishedChanged();

private slots:
    void on_executeBtn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QProcess *executeBash;

    bool m_running = false;
    int m_progressValue = 0;
    bool m_finished = false;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

this->executeBash = new QProcess(this);
    this->executeBash->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    /*connect(this->executeBash, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [script = this->executeBash](){
        qDebug() << "[EXEC] DATA: " << script->readAll();
    });*/
    connect(this->executeBash, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
          [script = this->executeBash](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
        qDebug() << "[EXEC] FINISHED: " << exitCode << exitStatus;
        if(script->bytesAvailable() > 0)qDebug() << "[EXEC] buffered DATA:" << script->readAll();
    });
    connect(this->executeBash, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [script = this->executeBash](QProcess::ProcessError error){
        qDebug() << "[EXEC] error on execution: " << error << script->errorString();
    });

    connect(this->executeBash, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [this, script = this->executeBash](){

         QString s = QString::fromUtf8(script->readAll());
         qDebug() << "[EXEC] DATA: " << s;
         auto match = QRegularExpression("Stage (\\d+)/(\\d+): (.*)").match(s);
         if (match.hasMatch()) {
             int x = match.captured(1).toInt();
             int y = match.captured(2).toInt();
             QString stage_info = match.captured(3);
             qDebug() << "x = " << x;
             qDebug() << "y = " << y;
             qDebug() << "info = " << stage_info;
             this->updateProgress(x * 100 / y);
         }
    });

    // Initialization of the progressbar
    m_running = false;
    emit runningChanged();
    m_finished = false;
    emit finishedChanged();
    updateProgress(0);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


// ProgressBag loading depending on the workload of the .sh file
float MainWindow::progress()
{
  return m_progressValue;
}

bool MainWindow::running()
{
  return m_running;
}

bool MainWindow::finished()
{
  return m_finished;
}

void MainWindow::startComputation()
{
  m_running = true;
  emit runningChanged();
  updateProgress(100);
}

void MainWindow::finishComputation()
{
  m_finished = true;
  emit finishedChanged();

  m_running = false;
  emit runningChanged();
}

void MainWindow::updateProgress(int value)
{
  m_progressValue = value;
  emit progressChanged();

  if (m_progressValue == 100)
      finishComputation();

  ui->progressBarExecuteScript->setValue(value);

}


void MainWindow::on_executeBtn_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Button clicked!";
    this->executeBash->start(QStringLiteral("/bin/sh"), QStringList() << QStringLiteral("/home/emanuele/catkin_docking_ws/devel/lib/test.sh")); //will start new process without blocking
    // right after the execution of the script the QProgressBar will start computing
    //ui->progressBarExecuteScript->setValue(executeBash->readAll().toInt());
}
```

**What I have done so far**

1) After setting up all the necessary points I came across [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752839/how-to-update-qprogressbar-while-executing-shell-script-in-qprocess) where the user had the same problem I have now but it was resolved via `QDir`, I am not sure about this solution though.

2) After going through the official documentation I found out about [future watcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html). I am new to this tool and am having difficulties understanding how to apply it and that is the reason why I created also the minimal verifiable example.

3) I tried to `setValue` of the progressbar based on the execution of the bash file. Or better its advancement as shown below:

```
ui->progressBarExecuteScript->setValue(executeBash->readAll().toInt());
```

I thought that this could have solved the problem but the `QProgressBar` stays at 0 value and I am not sure why.

4) I consulted the [QProgressBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html) official documentation but I didn't find anything to help me solve the problem.

Please point to the right direction to solve this issue.

Comment: I don't think that is possible to get the advencement of a `QProcess` because you don't know how many time the process can be alive. So a possible solution is to put 0 to min, max and current value of the progress bar to  have an infinite progress

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. You mean infinite progress in the meantime is working and when is done put the value to 100?

Comment: @Emanuele QProgressBar only shows the progress (it is a widget), it does not calculate it. The task of calculating is your job, for example if you download 100 files then you could point out that each files is 1%, but another developer could calculate the size of all the files in bytes and then calculate the progress as the download percentage in bytes And obviously both numbers are different, so if you do not know how to calculate it, then it is impossible for others to help you. In these it is better to set `progressbar->setRange(0, 0)` which will make a busy bar

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks for reading the question. The problem is that I don't know when the the first command will end (i.e. I don't know the physical time of the extraction of the `.csv`) and I don't know when the second command (i.e. the beginning of the second extraction and its duration) will take place.

Comment: So it looks like that `QProcess` is not a good choice?

Comment: @Emanuele No, there is no way to do it unless you can see the future :-). The idea of progress implies knowing how to quantify the total size and quantify how much progress has been made that clearly cannot be calculated in your case. My recommendation is that you use the QProgressBar as a busy bus.

Comment: I know that the whole file is 2 GB, could that be helpful?

Comment: @Emanuele The problem has nothing to do with QProcess, that class just launches the application and gives you log information and nothing else.

Comment: @eyllanesc, thank you very much that was useful. I have a last question for final clarification. If I have a `QListWidget` and I drag&drop for example 4 files (`.sh`) and decide to run all of them in one go. Based on what you suggest, there is no way to differentiate in this case when a `QProcess` finishes to process a file and start processing a new one until it reached the fourth file? Thanks :)

Comment: @eyllanesc, you suggested to use `QProgressBar` as a busy bus. That would just be setting  `ui->progressBarExecuteScript->setRange(0,0);` inside the function `on_executeBtn_clicked()`. As soon as the `QProcess` ends can I stop the busy progress somehow? Thank you very much for your time. It is very much appreciated!

Comment: Do the commands `rostopic echo ...` block until they are complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, modify the script to output which stage it is currently doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Stage 1/2: Scan"
rostopic echo -b test_LaserScan_PointCloud2_test2.bag -p /scan > test_landing_test_2.csv
echo "Stage 2/2: Velodyne"
rostopic echo -b test_LaserScan_PointCloud2_test2.bag -p /velodyne_points > vel_test_2.csv
```

I also added `set -e` to make it stop on the first failed command.

Now, you can look for these "Stage x/y" markers in the output stream and call `updateProgress` if so.

```
connect(this->executeBash, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [this, script = this->executeBash](){
     QString s = QString::fromUtf8(script->readAll());
     auto match = QRegularExpression("Stage (\\d+)/(\\d+): (.*)").match(s);
     if (match.hasMatch()) {
         int x = match.captured(1).toInt();
         int y = match.captured(2).toInt();
         QString stage_info = match.captured(3);
         this->updateProgress(x * 100 / y);
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for stopping by and reading the question. You solution works partially and in fact on terminal I can see the two flags being processed correctly :). However the `QProgressBar` does not move from 0. Am I missing something? I updated the question adding your answer that correctly triggers the `QProcess`

Comment: I think your first callback (with the `[EXEC] DATA`) eats the output before the second can get to it.

Comment: I found the missing piece! Basically I was not updating properly the progressbar and added `ui->progressBarExecuteScript->setValue(value);` in the function `updateProgress`. Also yes, you were right the first callback (with the `[EXEC] DATA`) was eating the output.

Comment: I posted in the question the correct working code adding your suggestion and adding the missing piece of the progressbar. Thank you for your help and time, very much appreciated! Also if you think my question was clear consider give me a thumbs-up :) .